# Is there a Drupal module for Forms with powerful CRUD style behaviour?

Tags: forms, drupal, drupal-modules, crud

We are building a website that contains a large number of database tables that need to be edited by the CMS administrator.
Some of the tables are fed by form submissions from users on the front end of the website.
Some of the tables are purely in the CMS and are used to create custom modules on the front end of the website.

Although there is a forms module in Drupal, I think our requirements cannot be met by it.
Does anyone know of a system that allows forms to be saved to a CRUD style database with the following features?

[image]
<sub>(source: [yart.com.au](http://www.yart.com.au/drupal/crudsummary.png))</sub>

1. Export of all database fields.
2. View a summary of the records in a filterable table.
3. With paging
4. You can have one to many relationships in records eg

[image]
<sub>(source: [yart.com.au](http://www.yart.com.au/drupal/cruddetail.png))</sub>

To code this manually for 10 forms is A LOT of work. Particularly the one to many relationships. If there is a powerful module available it would save us writing one.

Answer (score 5):

I have not used it at all so far, so I have no clue if it fits your needs, but the [Auto Admin module](http://drupal.org/project/autoadmin) seems to offer at least some of the features you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at CCK and check that doesn't meet your requirements before building something bespoke. All of your requirements can be met with a combination of [CCK](http://drupal.org/project/cck), Views, and a bit of tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

This CRUD operations can be achieved using Drupal 7 modules like data,schema,entity,views and ctools.
Nice article is here: http://subhojit777.in/crud-data-table-in-drupal/
In-place editing for Fields is also possible using quickedit module,but Backbone.js,Underscore.js libraries are required and your Theme should support.